# CodeIgniter - Array to String conversion error

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estoy creando una función para obtener datos de interpretes basados en el ID de interprete. Esta es la función que he creado:

interprete_model.php

**Models**

```
public function interpreteID($id)
{
        //consultar los datos
        $this->db->select('*');

        $this->db->where('id_interprete', $id);

        $this->db->from('tbl_interpretes');       

        $query = $this->db->get();

        if($query->num_rows() > 0 )
        {
            return $query->result();
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }   


}
```

Estoy llamando a este método en mi archivo interprete/perfil.php:

**Controller**

```
public function index()
{
        $id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
        echo "User ID ".$id;

        $query = $this->interprete_model->interpreteID($this->session->userdata('user_id'));

        echo "consultar los datos: ".$query;
        //vista
        $this->load->view('perfil_view',$data);
}
```

Cuando hago esto obtengo un error diciendo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

falta mostrar los datos en la web.

¿Podría alguien por favor decirme por qué está haciendo esto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que estas imprimiendo un arreglo como String, en tu modelo estas devolviendo `return $query->result();` que te devuelve un arreglo, si quieres imprimir este arreglo podrías usar print_r()

Tu controlador esta asi:

```
public function index()
{
        $id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
        echo "User ID ".$id;

        $query = $this->interprete_model->interpreteID($this->session->userdata('user_id'));

        echo "consultar los datos: ".$query; // El error esta aquí
        //vista
        $this->load->view('perfil_view',$data);
}
```

Podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
public function index()
{
        $id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
        echo "User ID ".$id;

        $query = $this->interprete_model->interpreteID($this->session->userdata('user_id'));

        echo "consultar los datos: "; 
        print_r($query); // Usar print_r() para imprimir el arreglo;
        //vista
        $this->load->view('perfil_view',$data);
}
```

Comment: Pinzon , Gracias , es correcto. necesito hablar contigo sobre codeiginter.

Comment: Genial. donde podemos hablar osea chat de stack overflow? :)

Comment: Acabo de crear una sala de chat https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58264/php-codeigniter