# codeigniter Message: Array to string conversion

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

buenas tardes comunidad espero me puedan ayudar a mandar un dato

**vista**

```
       <?php
       // $data = $this->User_model->getUsers();
        $data = array("data"=>$this->User_model->getUsers());
        var_dump($data)
?>
        <?php echo $data
?>
```

**error**
Message: Array to string conversion

[error](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/67681/codeigniter-array-to-string-conversion-error?rq=1)

[este](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/128740/problema-array-to-string-conversion)

Comment: Si `$data` es un array no puedes hacer  `echo` de él, debes leerlo de otro modo, mediante un bucle por ejemplo, o accediendo directamente a sus propiedades. Agrega a la pregunta lo que muestra el `var_dump` y dinos lo que quieres sacar de `$data`.

Answer (score 0):

Te falta enviarlo como `array` y asignarle un nombre, el cual recibirá en la vista. Puedes agregar más datos a la misma variable **$data**

```
public function index()
{       
 $data['prueba'] = "hello";
 $data['param2'] = "world";
 $this->load->view('side/ver',$data);    
}
```

En la vista:

```
<?php echo $prueba.' '.$param2; ?>
```

Comment: me sigue mandando el error

Comment: me manda este error  Message: Undefined variable $param2

Answer (score 0):

Las solicitudes a los modelos las debes realizar dentro del controller antes de cargar la vista y no dentro de la vista.

En tu función del controlador donde mandas a llamar ese modelo vas a definir una variable cualquiera que vas a pasar como parámetro a la hora de cargar la vista. Previamente, debes de haber cargado el modelo en el constructor del controlador.

```
$this->load->model('User_model');
```

Y esta es la función de tu vista:

```
public function index()
{       
 $params['data'] = $this->User_model->getUsers();
 $this->load->view('nombredetuvista',$params);    
}
```

Con esto en tu vista "nombredetuvista" puedes utilizar la variable `$data`, pero tu problema no está siendo utilizar la variable sino que estás intentando imprimir un arreglo como si fuera un String y no te lo va a permitir.

Intuyo que tu función te trae todos los usuarios, entonces si quieres imprimir todos los usuarios lo tienes que hacer con un `foreach()`

```
<?php foreach($data as $usuario){ ?>
    <span><?php echo $usuario; ?></span>
<?php } ?>
```

Esto también te va a dar error, si estás jalando tus usuarios por arreglo asociativo puedes imprimir sus valores así:

```
<?php foreach($data as $usuario){ ?>
    <span><?php echo $usuario['nombre']; ?></span>
<?php } ?>
```

Si lo estas jalando como objeto, puede ser asi:

```
<?php foreach($data as $usuario){ ?>
    <span><?php echo $usuario->nombre; ?></span>
<?php } ?>
```